# Ghost doc to add "modified by" comment

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ghostdoc

Is there a way to get ghost doc to modify an existing XML comment for a method (made by Ghost doc) to add a "modified by" line when you re run it on the method?

I personally think this is what source control is for, but they want to do it in the XML,
so it's a new work requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Disclosure: I represent the company that offers GhostDoc)

I agree with you that "modified by" belongs with source control and not XML comments.

But if you still want to get it done with GhostDoc you can use the  tag to hard code "modified by" in Options. This won't set set current date/time dynamically though.

If you need the current date/time option, you can get this done with GhostDoc Pro only - use its T4 template based comments to configure the "modified by" comment/section with the BCL DateTime.Now function for the current time.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Do you have an example of using the former or the latter on the Ghost doc site?

Comment: Eric, we don't have this particular example online right now but if you start a thread in the GhostDoc community forum at http://community.submain.com we will be happy to provide the examples there. Thanks!